# Framerate independent acceleration

Tags: actionscript-3, physics, formula

So I understand that, to get frame rate independent movement I have to multiply the base speed by (1000/delta). It works on values that represent speed, but when I try this with an acceleration variable, e.g. gravity, it won't work, it isn't even frame rate independent.

Is there a different formula for acceleration variables, or am I forgetting something else?

Example:

```
var Multiplier:Number = (GetDeltaTime()) / (1000 / 30);
jumpVelocity = -21 * Multiplier //works
gravity = 1.5 * Multiplier //dosn't work
```

This is called at the start of every frame

**Edit**: Found a solution, I had to square delta time. Not 100% sure why it works, but it does.

So:

```
jumpVelocity = -21 * Multiplier //unchanged
gravity = 1.5 * Math.pow(Multiplier,2) //works now
```

Comment: I know nothing about actionscript, but I do know physics and this makes no sense to me. Do you know the units? Could you give us some numbers, and tell us what's going wrong (not just "it won't work")?

Comment: Units are pixels/30th of a second. Basically, everything works except acceleration, gravity and friction. All of which alter the speed, not the coordinates. At higher frame rates, these values appear to increase (e.g faster acceleration, higher gravity).

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you want to do is measure the time that has passed since the last frame (the "frame time"), and add that to an accumulator.

You then forward your game's state by "fixed time steps" (e.g. 1/30th of a second) and subtract that simulated time from the accumulator until it is less than one time step.

So as an example:

- accumulator starts at 0
- fixed time step set to 33ms
- 1 frame passes at 20fps, the frame time was 1000ms/20 = 50ms
- 50ms added to accumulator
- game state is forwarded by 1 fixed time step (33ms), that time is subtracted from accumulator
- accumulator is now 17ms, which is less than one fixed time step -> game state is done updating
- continue to next frame
- 1 frame passes at 10fps, the frame time was 1000ms/10 = 100ms
- 100ms added to accumulator
- accumulator is now 117ms
- game state is forwarded by 1 fixed time step (33ms), that time is subtracted from accumulator
- accumulator is now 84ms, which is more than one fixed time step -> game state is not done updating
- game state is forwarded by 1 fixed time step (33ms), that time is subtracted from accumulator
- accumulator is now 51ms, which is more than one fixed time step -> game state is not done updating
- game state is forwarded by 1 fixed time step (33ms), that time is subtracted from accumulator
- accumulator is now 18ms, which is less than one fixed time step -> game state is done updating
- continue to next frame

There is an excellent article by Glenn Fiedler about just this issue. You can find it [here](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep).

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I had actually read that article before. I decided not to use it because, as stated in the last section of the article, a different number of steps might be taken every frame, making it choppy. The article offers a solution for this, but I'm working in flash and it would be too slow.

Comment: @simon To clarify: The whole idea with fixed time step physics is that it does _not_ look choppy. In fact, if you go one step further and interpolate states (which is mentioned at the end of the article), you will get the smoothest, best looking results that are at all possible, in any game, in any simulation, anywhere. Maybe [this link](http://www.gamepoetry.com/blog/2008/04/11/frame-based-code-sucks/) will help. Have a look at the two example swfs, maked "Frame Based Case Study" and "Timer Based Case Study" and tell me which looks choppy to you : )